# Eclipse shortcut keys do not work properly in Windows 10

Tags: eclipse

When I try to comment out multiple lines by `CTRL+ Shift + /`, it started working as `Collapse All` feature in Eclipse. I restored the defaults setting as recommended in other websites but did not help.

For instance, when I do `CTRL+ Shift + L`, I can see the Add Block Comment option and when I click it, it works. However, the shortcut shown as `CTRL+ Shift + /` is not working.

Here is my list of available key bindings using `CTRL+ Shift + L`:

[image: available key bindings]

How can I fix this problem?

Edit: Here is the screenshot of the list of the key bindings in **Window > Preferences > Keys**:

Second Edit: I use Windows 10 and I downloaded the last version of Eclipse which is 2019-09. I created a new project and a new Java class. The shortcut still works as collapse all.

I realized that `CTRL+ Shift + Numpad_Divide` is defined as collapse all. For some reason, my computer consider `/` as `Numpad_Divide` and does not function as comment out.

[image: PreferencesBindings]

Comment: More information is needed. Update your question to include a screen shot of the key binding(s) defined for **Ctrl+Shift+/** within Eclipse. To do that: [1] **Window > Preferences > Keys** [2] Click the **Binding** column to sort it in ascending order. [3] Scroll down the list to locate the binding(s) defined for **Ctrl+Shift+/**. [4] Take a screen shot and post it. (In my case, using the default settings in version _2019-06_, there are three such bindings.)

Comment: OK, there's nothing obviously wrong with the bindings, but there are a few more things to try: [1] Reproduce the problem, then check the workspace log (**Window > Show View > Error Log**). Were any relevant error messages logged? [2] [Start Eclipse with the **-clean** parameter](https://www.eclipsezone.com//eclipse/forums/t61566.html) to see if that helps. [3] Create a new workspace (**File > Switch Workspace > Other..**), then create a new throwaway project in the new workspace, then try `CTRL+ Shift + /` in some file in that project. Does the problem persist even in a new workspace?

Comment: @skomisa I tried all of them one by one and did not work. I removed Eclipse and reinstalling it. It looks like it did not change anything.

Comment: OK. [1] Please update your question to also specify your operating system, and your Eclipse version. [2] `CTRL + Shift + /` is working fine for me with Eclipse 2019-06 on Windows 10. [3] Are you definitely selecting the text to be commented in your _*.java_ file before using `CTRL + Shift + /`? [4] Following the reinstallation of Eclipse, is `CTRL + Shift + /` still performing _Collapse All_ instead of commenting the selected  code?

Comment: @skomisa [1] I did update my question. [3] Yes, I am. [4] Yes, it functions as ```Collapse All``` [5] I defined a new command for comment all as ```CTRL+C```, and it works for now. In order to remove the comments, I use ``CTRL+Shitf+\```. This is a temporary solution for me.

Comment: @skomisa I guess I figured out the problem and explained in the question. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: OK. [1] First, do you have one or two "`/`" keys on your keypad? I have two. [2] If you have two, does Eclipse run the _Collapse All_ command regardless of which "`/`" key you use with `CTRL + Shift + /`? [3] On my keyboard, if I use the **divide key on the number pad** with `CTRL + Shift + /` Eclipse runs the _Collapse All_ command, and that is expected behavior as defined in **Window > Preferences > Keys** for _Collapse All_. [4] If I use the **forward slash key** (to the immediate left of the SHIFT key) instead with `CTRL + Shift + /` Eclipse runs the _Add Block Comment_ command.

Comment: Yes, I have two of them and when I use **the forward slash key**, it works now. However, before when I use this feature, Eclipse was adding ```//``` before each line. Now, when I use ```CTRL+Shift+/```, ```/* ... */``` is being put. Do you think that it is because of a recent update? By the way, I am not able to accept the comment as an answer. If you'd like, just share your comment as answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most keyboards have two "`/`" keys, and the problem you experienced will arise if the incorrect "`/`" key is used when trying to *Add Block Comment* for selected code:

- The "`/`" key on the number pad is the divide key, and this is the key that must be used with `CTRL + Shift + /` to *Collapse All*.
- The "`/`" key to the immediate left of the `Shift` key is the forward slash key, and this is the key that must be used with `CTRL + Shift + /` to *Add Block Comment* for selected code.

You can see the distinction when viewing the **Tools > Preferences > General > Keys** screen, though it is not obvious at all:

- For *Collapse All*, Eclipse helpfully describes the divide key as "*Numpad_Divide*" for the binding:

  [image: NumpadDivideSlash]
- However, for *Add Block Comment* Eclipse only describes the forward slash key as "/" for the binding:

  [image: ForwardSlashKey]

Eclipse could remove the ambiguity if it described the forward slash key as "*Forward_Slash*" instead of "*/*".

Answer (score 4):

Just throwing this for future users:

I had the same issue on my eclipse. I am using windows 10 as well.

Anyway before the commands <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>numpad...</kbd> will work first you need to "enable" this mode by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>numpad_divide</kbd>. You will notice that next to all functions little minus signs will apear. Once you do that you will be able to use colapse, colapse all, expand, expand all.

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>numpad_divide</kbd> again will disable this mode and you won't be able to use those shortcuts.